# Cannot find php-fpm.conf

Tags: php, configuration, cgi, fastcgi, fpm

I use php-fastcgi via nginx on Ubuntu 21.10, and I want to set the `log_limit` php-fpm directive to `8000` for my PHP logs not to be truncated, but I can't find `php-fpm.conf` anywhere.

The closest file I can find is `/etc/php8.0/cgi/php.ini` and I inserted `log_limit = 8000` into it, but `phpinfo()` doesn't output it unlike the `log_errors_max_len` PHP configuration variable, and PHP log entries keep getting truncated.

Comment: did you try `locate php-fpm.conf`

Comment: I previously tried to find `php-fpm-conf` in `/etc` with the Midnight Commander. I've just installed `locate`, and `locate php-fpm.conf` didn't yield any results.

Comment: usually it is here `/etc/php/8.0/fpm`. That's an unusuall php location you got. How did you install php?

Comment: I installed PHP 8 with `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php; apt install php8.0`. There's no `/etc/php/8.0/fpm`.

Comment: Did you install the extension: **apt install php8.0-fpm** (ubuntu) or similar command for your OS?

Comment: To my surprise, `apt install php8.0-fpm` installed the package, so it wasn't installed before, and it created `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`. Various Apache-specific dependencies have also been installed which suggests that PHP-FPM is used with Apache. I use nginx, and I don't ever plan to use Apache. I have six `/usr/bin/php-cgi` processes running on the server which work together with nginx. The question still remains: How can I solve the truncated log issue?

Comment: Both Apache and Nginx use php-fpm. Neither installs the module. For php-fpm configuration parameters to be in effect, the module must be activated (for Apache) or the VirtualHosts must be configured for php-fpm. I am not sure what the procedure is for Nginx. Most likely you have another configuration in use, so the log_limit is being specified in the wrong configuration.

Comment: Note: cgi/php.ini is not related to php-fpm.

Comment: I stand corrected. Given that I use php-cgi, I assume I have nothing to do with PHP-FPM. I'm still interested in how I can make my PHP log entries not truncated. The relevant options I use in `/etc/php/8.0/cgi/php.ini` are `log_errors_max_len = 8000`, `log_limit = 8000`, and `decorate_workers_output = no`. I assume `log_limit` is ignored since it's a PHP-FPM option.

Comment: Tip: Since you are using PHP 8.x, I would not use the ancient php-cgi. Use php-fpm and uninstall php-cgi. I would also delete this question and create a new one with only the log issue.

Comment: I've migrated to php-fpm, and some log lines are still truncated, such as https://gist.github.com/mondalaci/7c069c13bf9739a9416ad228375cde9a - In `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini`, I have `log_errors_max_len = 8000`. In `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`, I have `log_limit = 8000`. In `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, I have `decorate_workers_output = no`. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, I had to `apt install php8.0-fpm` which created `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`. Thanks to @john-hanley for revealing the root cause!

My truncated logs issue is still unresolved; I'll open a new question specifically for it.